# Why don't the vampires sparkle at the start of the movie?

Tags: twilight

In the beginning of the Twilight (2008) movie, when the Cullens walk into the school it's sunny outside, yet they don't sparkle.  Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part in the movie to which you are referring is around 0:09:00. If you look at 0:05:45, you can see the skies are completely overcast and the daylight is indirect light that has filtered through the clouds.

The constant cloudiness is, in fact, the entire reason why the Cullens have moved to Forks. According to The Rules for the Twilight universe, only direct sunlight causes them to glitter and so, in Forks they are almost completely safe from exposing their secret.

Comment: "According to The Rules for the Twilight universe, only direct sunlight causes them to glitter" would be good to have a source for that.

Comment: There is no direct source, but the only times that they do glitter are in direct sunlight, such as the scene in the meadow in Twilight.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the actual sunlight doesn't hit them, they won't sparkle.

HERE'S THE REASON THEY DO SPARKLE::

https://www.quora.com/Why-do-vampires-sparkle-and-dont-die-in-sun-in-Twilight

Comment: The question here isn't why _do_ they sparkle, it's why, in this particular scene, they are not shown to sparkle.  Again, please don't post comments as answers.